# How do I create a content slider with left and right and other slide options using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am a bit new to this part of JQuery/JavaScript.

I know I can use a jquery plugin or slider from somewhere but I think my requirements are a bit different.

I created content with background images and text on top of them and the content is prepared.  I need to use jquery to make the content change to the next content when an image on top is clicked and when the left/right options are clicked.  Similar to the way a slider would work.  I also need to go it left and right options to back and forth.

How can I get started on this?

Comment: I hate to be the one to do this, but what have you tried so far? What code have you thought of? Have you drawn out your requirements on a whiteboard or piece of paper? Often for something visual like this, doing that will show you how it should be coded. Finally there are a million different tutorials out there for javascript sliders. I am sure that there are dozens that you could look at and modify to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to wrap the whole content in a division with a fixed width, then you can use the [jQuery animate api](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to change the width of the content dynamically to left or right using jquery animate option.
example to move content to left

```
$('#innerscroll').animate({"left": "+=150px"}, 500);
```

example to move content to right

```
$('#innerscroll').animate({"left": "-=150px"}, 500);
```

innerscroll is the parent division id to which slider is wrapped

The detail step is given in this [jQuery image slider tutorial](http://sreevathsabv.blogspot.in/p/simple-jquery-image-gallery-tutorial.html), make sure you use li tags instead of img for your contents.. you can improvise on the same.

Comment: But I won't be using background image.  I mean I have a body background image and then the slider background is transparent.  I am using the opacity property for the background.  Can I still make it work using what you have above? Thanks @sree!

Comment: yes , all u have to do is wrap it inside a container with fixed with and move those many pixels to left or right...